# aws athena-read csv file where values contain commas

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, delimiter, amazon-athena

I have a table like so

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS something (
  ...
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   ) 
LOCATION 's3://...'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

but some fields contain a comma like (8-10,99) without quotes. the csv is too large to be opened on excel. is there any way to change the delimiter or make athena read this file?

Comment: Are those fields enclosed in quotes, eg: `"8-10,99"` ? If not, there would be no easy way for Athena to discern which commas are 'within' a field and which are not. Is there any formatting in the file like that to assist in identifying the column better? How big is the file?

Comment: I'm afraid, you still need some tool to change delimiter of CSV file and Athena wouldn't handle it out of the box. Nonetheless, You can change the file format using CTAS (ex: parquet) to avoid delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are comma-separated, but contain commas without escaping there is no way for any automated tool to distinguish between a comma that represents a separator between fields and one that is meant to be content. In other words, the files are malformed and have to be fixed. If you have the option of generating the files again either make sure that fields are quoted, or use a separator that will not appear in the fields, such as a tab character.